# Packages in same namespace: can't import module in setup script

Tags: python, setuptools, namespace-package

I'm curious about the following situation. Let's say I have two projects named `project_alpha` and `project_bravo`, both defining a top-level namespace package `mymeta`. The layout:

```
project_alpha/
   -> mymeta/
        -> __init__.py
        -> project_alpha/
             -> __init__.py
             -> version.py
   -> setup.py

project_bravo/
   -> mymeta/
        -> __init__.py
        -> project_bravo/
             -> __init__.py
             -> version.py
   -> setup.py
```

Both `mymeta/__init__.py`s contain only the line `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` (according to [namespace section in setuptools docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages)). Contents of both `version.py`s:

```
__version_info__ = (0, 9, 9, 'dev0')
__version__ = '.'.join((str(entry) for entry in __version_info__))
```

The `setup.py` script for `project_alpha` is pretty simple. The namespace package `mymeta` is declared, and the version is taken from the `version` module:

```
# project_alpha
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from mymeta.project_alpha.version import __version__

setup(
    name='mymeta.project-alpha',
    version=__version__,
    namespace_packages=['mymeta'],
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

The `setup.py` script for `project_bravo` has the same structure, but with a twist: `project_bravo` depends on `project_alpha` when building:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from mymeta.project_bravo.version import __version__

setup(
    name='mymeta.project-bravo',
    version=__version__,
    namespace_packages=['mymeta'],
    setup_requires=['mymeta.project-alpha'],
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

When building `project_bravo`, I get the following error:

```
~/project_bravo $ python setup.py sdist 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 156, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 276, in run
    return func()
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 245, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-ahmxos98/mymeta.project-alpha-0.9.9.dev0/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    try:
ImportError: No module named 'mymeta.project_alpha'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    packages=find_packages(),
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 853, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1125, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1137, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1115, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 249, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 168, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 143, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 156, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 276, in run
    return func()
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 245, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/tmp/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-ahmxos98/mymeta.project-alpha-0.9.9.dev0/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    try:
ImportError: No module named 'mymeta.project_alpha'
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand the error here. It has something to do with the imports order, right? If I comment out the import of `mymeta.project_bravo.version` in `project_bravo/setup.py` and replace the `version` with some hard-coded string, suddenly the build succeeds...

---

Edit: I introduced a workaround for this issue. Instead of trying to import the version directly, I `exec` the version module to avoid the import problems. Of course, this is not a proper solution, thus not posting this as answer, but still here it is:

```
__version__ = None # if the exec fails, leave the version unset, the resulting build version will be 0.0.0
version_script_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'mymeta', 'project_alpha', 'version.py'))
with open(version_script_path) as version_script:
    exec(version_script.read())
```

After the version script is read and executed, the version is initialized, thus no need to import anything from `mymeta` package.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error but I couldn't. On my system everything works fine. Maybe try with a fresh virtualenv? How do you provide `mymeta.project_alpha` before you try to build `mymeta.project_bravo`? Do you do `setup.py install` in `mymeta.project_alpha`?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that. I issue `python setup.py sdist upload` to upload `project_alpha` to a private PyPI repo.

Comment: Hmm, issuing `python setup.py install` works for me either, but this explicitly installs `project_alpha` to the venv so the package is already present when building `project_bravo`. The issue appears only when `setuptools` tries to download `project_alpha`s egg into `project_bravo/.eggs` dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost one year later, I once again faced this issue and the solution for `python>=3.3` is to use implicit namespace packages as specified in [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). The project structure is barely changed, just both the `__init__.py`s for pkgutil-style namespace package `mymeta` are gone:

```
project_alpha/
   -> mymeta/
        -> project_alpha/
             -> __init__.py
             -> version.py
   -> setup.py

project_bravo/
   -> mymeta/
        -> project_bravo/
             -> __init__.py
             -> version.py
   -> setup.py
```

To make `setuptools` happy, both setup scripts need to be adjusted as well:

```
...
setup(
    ...
    packages=['mymeta.' + pkg for pkg in find_packages('mymeta')],
)
```

Now the imports will be resolved correctly when building `project-bravo`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: The command

```
$ python setup.py sdist
```

for `mymeta.project_bravo` downloads an egg of `mymeta.project_alpha` from a private pypi repo.

Namespace packages are very delicate concerning their imports.

e.g. I found out that when I install `ns.a` and `ns.b` regularly in my environment and supply the import path of `ns.d` in a .pth file in the site-packages directory, it will not work, no matter what. However when I symlink to `ns.d` in site-packeges/ns directory it will work.

If I install none of the components and supply all paths in a .pth in the site-packages directory, everything works fine.

If I install all of the components regularly also everything works fine.

Just when I mix concepts it will not work.

Therefore I suspect that this might also be the issue here: Different strategies for the import paths.

You might want to try to modify your `__init__.py` file to:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path

__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

I regret my decision to do namespace packages. I would never do it again.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help. Nevertheless, thank you for your efforts as the answer explains the origin of the error, which gives me a direction for further digging!

Comment: Hi, if you are still interested in a solution, I found one for at least python 3.3 and newer - the implicit namespace packages. See my answer for details.